# css hierarchy for queries and background-image

Tags: html, css, media

I have idea to make different size of background-image for table pc and mobile version of my site. For example:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .myImage {
   background-image:url(image_small.jpg);
   }
}

.myImage {
background-image:url(image_big.jpg);
}
```

Is there any kind of hierarchy to override my picture in browsers? Do **mobile** browser will load image_big.jpg in it's cache or something similar? And do i need to implement my css file in any kind of order in html to achieve what i want?(stop browser from downloading my image_big for mobile)

Pardon for my english

Comment: Your two rules are the wrong way round in the code above. CSS Specificity says that since both your rules have the same selector: `.myImage`, the last one wins, and it will therefore use the big image even at small screen sizes. It is usual in responsive coding to but the base CSS rule first (ie the one not inside a media query), followed by the media queries. That avoids the mistake shiown here. As to your last question, Yes, the order of your CSS files in the HTML is critical, since where rules in different spreadsheets have equal specificity, the last one overrules earlier ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer each of your questions in turn:

**1. Is there any kind of hierarchy to override my picture in browsers?**

- Unsure what you are referring to, the image applied is determined by CSS [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) / [**cascade**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) / basic selection. The image shown is either the only one identified by an applicable rule, the last listed in a series of applicable rules, or the one listed in an applicable rule with the most specificity

**2. Do mobile browser will load image_big.jpg in it's cache or something similar?**

- No, see below

**3. And do i need to implement my css file in any kind of order in html to achieve what i want?(stop browser from downloading my image_big for mobile)**

- No, although browser dependant, the major browsers do not (seem to) load inapplicable images (tested Chrome 32, FF10, IE9). An image is deemed inapplicable if the CSS selector is not found relevent in the loaded DOM.

Additionally, this is a [**great article**](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) relating to asset loading and media queries